# SWT: height of Group

Tags: java, swt, jface

I want the height of `grpModelProperties` be lower. What should I do to distances of above and bottom of the text box in the group be the same?

```
public void createControl(Composite parent) {

     Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);
     composite.setLayout(new FillLayout());

     Group grpModelProperties = new Group(composite, SWT.SHADOW_IN);
     grpModelProperties.setText("ETL Transformation Model");
     grpModelProperties.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));


     GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
     text = new Text(grpModelProperties, SWT.NONE);
     text.setLayoutData(data);

     Button button = new Button(grpModelProperties, SWT.PUSH);
     button.setText("File System...");
     button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
     public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
     FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(getShell(), SWT.NULL);
     String path = dialog.open();

     if (path != null) {
     File file = new File(path);
     if (file.isFile())
      displayFiles(new String[] { file.toString()});
      else
      displayFiles(file.list());

     }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified `FillLayout` for the `Composite` containing the `Group` so the group is being stretched to fill the dialog area.

Use a different layout for the composite:

```
Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);
composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());

Group grpModelProperties = new Group(composite, SWT.SHADOW_IN);
grpModelProperties.setText("ETL Transformation Model");
grpModelProperties.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

// Layout data for the group in the composite,
// Fill the row, stays at the top of the dialog
grpModelProperties.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));
```

Here I have used `GridLayout` and set the `GridData` for the group to just fill the row.